# Cannot share files with Google Drive api/sdk

Tags: google-drive-api

Code lines:

```
var client = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient(key);
client.setItemIds([pathId]);
client.showSettingsDialog();
```

It always shows an error message:

> Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later

in message box.

Answer (score 0):

In order to share an item, you need to authenticate your requests with a user. Usage of `key` doesn't work in this case. Go through the regular OAuth 2.0 flow and authorize and authenticate for a user.

Comment: does it mean that gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId,       scope: scopes, immediate: false}); is not enough in this case?